# Add to favorites functionality using Jquery in CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php

I am currently working on a tour website, where the number of destinations is available for the user. A Login user can like any destination which will be added to his favorites destination section. I have done this task successfully. But after liked the destination the like button appears multiple times or equal to the number of likes have the user done. Maybe I am wrong in my logic here is my code. The first loop is fetching all the destination and the second loop fetching the favorites destination.
Note:-**Here I am showing only logic code not complete HTML or other PHP code**

```
<?php foreach($listing_data as $list){ ?>
<?php foreach($favorites as $fav){ if($fav['link_id']==$list['id']){?>
      <li class="pull-right"> <a  class="Theme" id="liked"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> </a> </li>
      <?php } else {?>
      <li class="pull-right"> <a href=""  class="Theme" id="liked"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> </a> </li>
      <?php } } }?>
```

Comment: so what is your goal, show 1 like only? can you please explain.

Comment: There is no jquery or anything related to CodeIgniter in your provided code. If you have to loop through two arrays matching on ID's then it sounds like you could simplify this with a better sql query.

Comment: @Vickel exactly. Currently, the like expression showing multiple times or equal to how I made a total like to a destination.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes, I mention only logic code where the issue occurs. The rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a helper variable

and take out the html in 2th foreach. 
$like = false; in each Site 
Then in each site you loop $favorites, then walk in $favorites for check if TheSite is liked; 
after second foreach you should compare if $like is true for use class "fas" or false for use class "far"

```html
<?php foreach($listing_data as $list){
  $like = false;
  foreach($favorites as $fav){
    if($fav['link_id']==$list['id']){
      $like = true;
    }
  }
  if($like){ ?>
    <li class="pull-right">
      <a  class="Theme" id="liked"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>           
    </li>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <li class="pull-right">
      <a href=""  class="Theme" id="liked"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> </a> 
    </li>
  <?php 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have one other issue maybe its related to jquery. When I click on the like expression the page refresh and not added to the favorites section, after refresh the page jquery code works fine and added to favorite section as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a refactoring of the code to make it look a bit cleaner.
The links are not included as they are ? and also use id's that will not be unique.

So the code could become something like...

```
<?php foreach ($listing_data as $list): ?>
    <?php

    foreach ($favorites as $fav) {
        $like = ($fav['link_id'] == $list['id']);
    }
    ?>

    <li class="pull-right">
        <?php if ($like): ?>
            <span>More Sensible Link 1</span>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>More Sensible Link 2</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```